# Does Yii2 AR class can check, does two objects has a link?

Tags: yii2, active-record-query

In Kohana that was performed as `$user->has('departments', array('id' => $dep->id_department))`

I dont see the same in Yii2

```
$customer = Customer::findOne(123);

$order = new Order();
$order->save(); // now its id is - 33

$customer->link('orders', $order); // let think relation is via table
```

And now I want to check If my **$customer** HAS this object linked **Order::find(33)**

Comment: If you defined relation in model you can check it by `isset($model->relationName)`

Comment: I want not to check does relation defined, but I want to check is SomeObject linked through junction table to my Model. So i want to know HAS my MODEL some OBJECT attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found very **ugly way** to do this.

```
$customer ->getOrders()->where(['id' => 33])->exists();
```

Is there are **shorter and pretty** solutions, as its in Kohana does ?

*Kohana* way:

```
$customer ->has('orders', ['id' => 33])
```